# How to show this function is increasing? Related to Normal distribution.

Tags: derivatives, normal-distribution

Numerically, it seems the following function $F(x)$ is increasing in $x$. How can I show it analytically?

$$F(x)=G(x)L'(x)$$

where $L(x)=\frac{(1-G(x))^3}{G'(x)}$ and $G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{e^{- \frac{ 1}{2} y^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} dy$, and $L'(x)$ is derivative of $L(x)$. Note that $G(\cdot)$ can be interpreted as the CDF of standard normal distribution and $L(\cdot)$ is proportional to inverse hazard rate of standard normal distribution. We can show that $L(\cdot)$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start:

Let
$\phi(x)
=\frac{e^{- \frac{ 1}{2} x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 
$.

From
$G(x)
=\int_{-\infty}^x \phi(y) \, dy
$,
$G'(x)=\phi(x)
$
and
$1-G(x)=\int_x^{\infty} \phi(y) \, dy$.

Also,
$$G(x)
=1-\phi(x)(x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{3\cdot 5}+\frac{x^7}{3\cdot 5 \cdot 7}
+\cdots)
=1-\phi(x)(x+h(x))
$$
so
$1-G(x)=\phi(x)(x+h(x))$
and
$L(x)
=\frac{(1-G(x))^3}{G'(x)}
=\frac{(\phi(x)(x+h(x)))^3}{\phi(x)}
=\phi^2(x)(x+h(x))^3
$.

Then
$L'(x)
=2\phi(x)\phi'(x)(x+h(x))^3
+3\phi^2(x)(x+h(x))^3(1+h'(x))
$.

I'm not sure how to
carry on from here,
so this is where I'll stop.